# labelling vertices in a graph in an optimal way problem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, discrete-optimization

given a set of n points in the plane and a set S of non ordered pairs of integers from 1 to n.
if i label all the points with the numbers from 1 to n, i can considered the set S the edges of a graph.
How can i efficiently found a labelling of the points such that the sum of the length of the edges is minimal?

Comment: How does labeling the points in the plane affect the sum of the edges?

Comment: What do you mean by _sum of the edges_?

Comment: oh i meant the sum of the length of the edges, i edited it.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you want to embed the graph in the plane, with each node corresponding to one of the specified points, in a way that minimizes the total edge length.
This is an instance of the [quadratic assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_assignment_problem).  The flow for pairs in $S$ is $1$, and the flow for pairs of points not in $S$ is $0$.